# Get all views of an app- every moment?

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to find a way to create some class that is always alive in the app. This class **doesn't know anything about the other classes in the project**. It will be able to "follow" all `UIViews` on screen-so every moment I can check(loop) over the views and get a pointer to each of them.

It has to run live, and always check positions of views (is it a memory problem?)

Why a pointer? because I need to know everything about it, so if its some kind of moving animation, or maybe it has some meta data like tags, etc. so only knowing there is some view at a certain position is not enough.

Is it possible in `iOS` ?

Comment: What do you mean by run live? Do you want to be able to access the views tree at any time you want or do you want to get notified on any changes to that tree (view added/removed/resized etc)?

Comment: I would like to only get data about them when ever I want, not affecting them at all, just get access to them, so I can check all sort of things such as position, color, tags, meta data, etc

Comment: The real purpose is to check them all the time, and set some "if statements" to some things

Comment: You should have a reference to the rootWindow in your app delegate - you can traverse the view hierarchy from there

Comment: @Paul.s thanks, can you show some simple example to get me going?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want me to show in an example. If you have the window then you can traverse it's subviews using it's `subviews` property. You can do this recursively all the way done to the views with no children

Comment: @Paul.s for example evey time any view is out of screen, even part of it, I need to get a pointer of it.

Comment: You probably want to update your question to be more specific if you are wanting actual examples. Also sounds like you would need to profile this as constantly polling all the views in your application sounds like it could be expensive and bad for battery usage

Comment: You are right I will edit it. So you think the best way is to send any view's pointer to some high class that will always keep an eye on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea sounds like an antipattern. However, …

Simply traverse the view tree and add a KVO handler to every view for every interesting property.

```
- (void)traverseSubviewsOfParentView:(UIView*)view
  for( UIView* subview in view.subviews )
  {
    [view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew];
    …
    [self traverseSubviewsOfParentView:subview context:NULL];
  }
```

Then implement the observation method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context 
{
  if( [@"frame" isEqualToString:keyPath] )
  {
    // Do what you want to do
  }
  …
}
```

Additionally you have to observe the `subviews` property of every view to get notified, when a view is inserted or removed.